# Angular 2: Katakana Regex

Tags: angular, regex, angular2-template, angular2-forms, katakana

I want to validate if the inputted text is in Katakana.

I have this:

```
Validators.pattern('[\u30A0-\u30FF]+')
```

But I also want to accept spaces in between. What should I add?

Comment: `[\u30A0-\u30FF\s]`?

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve here. Do you want individual Katakana words separated by spaces?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem. I added `\.<space>`

```
Validators.pattern('[\u30A0-\u30FF\. ]+')
```

This accepts Katakana characters and space/s in input field

Comment: You may also use Torazaburo's solution, `'[\u30A0-\u30FF\\s]'`. Or adding a dot - `'[\u30A0-\u30FF\\s.]'`